# Disable two-finger swipe on Firefox

Tags: mac, firefox, touchpad

When I scroll along the page or some scrollbox with two fingers on MacBook Pro touchpad, and it can be no longer scrolled to the left, Firefox decides I want to go back in history.

What can I do to disable history navigation using two-finger swipe in Firefox 17? I'm happy with using Backspace for going backwards, and wiping out all the text I was writing somewhere in some forms when I accidentally scroll more than I'm allowed is really frustrating.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I like the following solution better (than the existing answer) because it only affects Firefox:

1. In Firefox, go to "**about:config**"
2. Change the value for "**browser.gesture.swipe.left**" to "**cmd_scrollLeft**" (instead of "*Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate*")
3. Change the value for "**browser.gesture.swipe.right**" to "**cmd_scrollRight**" (instead of "*Browser:ForwardOrForwardDuplicate*")

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Finally there is solution that WORKS. Thank you so much! And welcome to SuperUser — good start :)

Comment: I know it is against policy to leave "thank you" comments, but that issue was haunting me for years already. Thanks!

Comment: Still works with Firefox Quantum (tested with 68.3esr) under OSX Mojave (tested with 10.14.6). Yay!

Comment: Does this solution still work for mac users? I want to turn swipe=back off on linux (FF 100), but can't make it happen..

Comment: thank you! :) what a stupid default setting!!!

Answer (score 17):

UPDATE:

There is a native way to do this. Go to System Preferences / Trackpad / More Gestures and deactivate the checkbox for "Swipe between pages" (first checkbox). This works at least for Mountain Lion.

---

The old, non-functional answer was:

I do not know of a native option in OSX (ML, 10.8.x), but there is a nice trick to do it:

Download the free [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de). It lets you map a huge amount of functions to trackpad & mouse gestures as well as keyboard shortcuts. You can set "No action" and you can decide, which applications should know your new custom gesture/shortcut.

So I just mapped the two finger swipe (left & right) to "No action" only for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and Sleipnir.

Hugely useful and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Good first post. Sounds like a potential solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, tried on OSX Lion (10.7.x) and latest currently available BTT — it surely handles two-finger swipes in either direction, but default action (e.g. history navigation) is also triggered with wherever action I set for swipe in BTT. So if I set "show Mission Control" action for swipe, I get both history navigation AND mission control invokation. :( Is there something additional to look for?

Comment: Oops. How embarrassing! Good: I tested it myself before posting. Bad: I tried it on a browser tab without a history (so obviously there is nowhere to swipe to).

But: I got it working. In System preferences / Trackpad / More Gestures.

I can set "Swipe between pages" off. This works for me (Mountain Lion)

I am updating the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Disabling system-wide swipe gesture disables it not only in Firefox, but also in Preview and Finder, and other apps where it's considered useful, and makes them inconvenient to use.