# How do I disable Option + Swipe navigating history (forward and back) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, touchpad

I hold down option and swipe up or down with two fingers on my trackpad, and Firefox is navigating forward and back in history.  How do I disable this behavior?  (I am using version 57.0 on Mac OX 10.13.1)

I have tried disabling the Mac system preference for "swipe between pages", and I have tried changing the value of browser.gesture.swipe.left and right to cmd_scrollLeft and Right ([as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/523169/disable-two-finger-swipe-on-firefox)).  Neither of these solutions addressed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

After going into `about:config`, set `mousewheel.with_alt.action` to `0`.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It works.