# How to disable back-forward action when swiping horizontally on trackpad in firefox on linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, touchpad

Since a couple of weeks my Firefox installation (Nightly, now on FF 100.0.2) on Linux (Guix, X11, Gnome 40.4) goes back or forward in history when I swipe horizontally on the touchpad (with two fingers). For me, this happens very often by accident, and never intentionally; how can this swipe-back behavior be disabled?

I've tried to set:

- [widget.disable-swipe-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201907/touchscreen-gestures-are-not-working-in-firefox-on-windows-10-11-despite-being-e) to true
- [mousewheel.with_alt.action](https://superuser.com/a/1270909/13089) to 0
- [browser.gesture.swipe.left](https://superuser.com/a/642368/13089) to cmd_scrollLeft
- browser.history_swipe_animation.disabled to true (source lost)

in `about:config`, but none of those options disable the swipe-back feature.

The result of setting [mousewheel.with_alt.action](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Mouse_Wheel_Scrolling) to 3 is that horizontal swiping on the touchpad now leads to both zooming of the contents and also going back and forward in history. So maybe two different settings are conflicting with each other.

Other things that don't work:

- Setting the environment variable `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=0`.
- Switching from Gnome to XFCE.

Comment: Maybe try to set environment variable: `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=0`, opposite of what's suggested [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1539730#c24) to enable it.

Comment: Just tried MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=0, but doesn't help either...

Comment: Maybe my firefox version is too old, browsing through https://searchfox.org/ shows that several of the relevant source code files have been updated pretty recently..

Comment: FWIW, I still fail to turn of swiping left/right to go back and forward in history with Firefox 109. However, it doesn't happen by accident anymore, for unknown reasons, so my immediate problem is solved.

Comment: I found another answer that solved it for me https://superuser.com/a/642368/238869